# How to check if an api response matches a Java class?

Tags: karate

In my project I have some DTO classes that I use in my REST communication. With Karate I want to create some external e2e/integration tests where I check if the API responses comply with the contract defined in the DTOs. To keep the whole setup DRY I want to avoid manually writing Karate JSON schemas describing the DTOs. Instead I am looking for a way to translate my Java classes into Karate JSON schemas.

#### What I already have:

Let's say this is one of my Java DTOs.

```
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@SuperBuilder
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonPropertyOrder({"elements", "property_1", "property_2"})
public class MyComplexTypeListDTO extends MyBaseAPIResponseDTO {
    private List<MyComplexType> elements;
}
```

I have a transformer using [jsonschema-generator](https://github.com/victools/jsonschema-generator) that gives me the [JSON-Schema](http://json-schema.org/) representation of my class.

```
private static JsonNode getSchemaFor(Class clazz) {
        JacksonModule module = new JacksonModule();
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        SchemaGeneratorConfigBuilder configBuilder = new SchemaGeneratorConfigBuilder(objectMapper, SchemaVersion.DRAFT_2019_09, OptionPreset.PLAIN_JSON)
                .with(module);
        SchemaGeneratorConfig config = configBuilder.build();
        SchemaGenerator generator = new SchemaGenerator(config);

        return generator.generateSchema(clazz);
    }
```

However Karate's schema definitions are different and the result fails to match. So I either need a translator from Java classes to Karate's schema directly or a translator/other kind of glue between JSON-Schema and Karate's flavor of JSON schema.

Is there a way to check if an API response matches a Java class in Karate that I am missing? Is there a convenient transformation library for any of the steps I'm missing or do I have to write my own?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I very strongly recommend that you do NOT re-use your production DTO-s for your tests. Think about it, you are setting yourself up for failure - and run the risk of not realizing when a "refactoring" that someone applied via the IDE etc. breaks your API clients.

You should be testing from the perspective of clients which for many teams is a web-browser. That is why Karate avoids Java and sticks to JSON + HTTP.

Second, testing for schema-fit has very little value in my honest opinion. Based on what you said, it is quite likely that your JSON is being generated from the DTO-s already, which makes it even less valuable in your specific case.

Sorry if that sounds harsh, but I see this mistake made all over the place. Being DRY is [over-rated](https://testing.googleblog.com/2019/12/testing-on-toilet-tests-too-dry-make.html) especially in a test-automation context.

That said, if you are lucky, the [`karate.toJson()`](https://twitter.com/KarateDSL/status/1184450203614498817) method would be able to convert your DTO-s into JSON, but if you are using some fancy annotations it may not work, it is all based on the JavaBean conventions.

Finally I would say just use Java inter-op, call some Java library to do schema validation and call it a day as seen in `schema.feature` over [here](https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/master/karate-demo).

To summarize, I think you should forget about schema validation and focus on testing the "business flows" of your API-s, where you typically chain API-s. Create product. Create order. Check if inventory is reduced. Etc etc. Once you have those in place, *then* think about whether it is worth testing for schema-fit or not.